# How can I get data from from two different tables in a single MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, database

I want to get data from two tables in my database. Here's what my tables might look like:

- table 1 with fields id, author, profession, country
- table 2 with fields id, quote, author, category

I want to select quote and author from table 2 and the corresponding profession from table 1, with the same author in both tables.

How do I construct a query that does this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Supposing that your `author` column contains unique identifiers for authors, try:

```
SELECT t2.quote, t2.author, t1.profession
FROM table2 t2
  LEFT JOIN table1 t1 ON t2.author = t1.author
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select T2.quote, T2.author, T1.profession
   from table1 T1, tabel2 T2
   where T1.id = T2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT table2.quote, table2.author, table1.profession FROM table2, table1 WHERE table2.author=table1.author

you can add LIMIT 1 at the end to have single result.